# A basic query regarding entanglement probability

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is it possible to create an entangled pair where they are either $(00)$ or $(11)$. But the probability of $(00)$ on measurement is say $(x)$% and $(11)$ is $(100-x)$% for any arbitrary $x$.

I suppose the answer is yes but need a confirmation?

And is there a talk (for laymen) on how do we create an actual entangled pair (physically). Would be very helpful

Comment: Are you asking whether such a state _could_ exist, or are you asking whether it's possible to _practically produce_ such a state using current technology?

Comment: the theoretical possibility of the existence of such a pair. But i am guessing that since you are distinguishing b/w the two it might not be possible to create such a pair practically for arbitrary x. is that so ?

Comment: anyone..........?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, such a state definitely exists. The state

$$\sqrt{p}|00\rangle+\sqrt{1-p}|11\rangle$$

has probability $p$ of being measured as $|00\rangle$ and probability $1-p$ of being measured as $|11\rangle$.

As far as actually *producing* such a state, it should be fairly straightforward. Produce a 50-50 entangled state (there are various ways to do this, for example using spontaneous parametric downconversion for entangled photons) and rotate your basis of measurement in the correct way.

Comment: just a follow up: when we create an entangled pair of the form $\sqrt{1/2}|00\rangle+\sqrt{1/2}|11\rangle$ no matter what direction we measure the 'spin' of a single particle in (one is with Alice another with Bob) each case (00 and 11) has the 50% probability of occurrence (as long as both are measured in same direction). Would this be true for the above created pair as well (instead of 50:50 the probability being x:(100-x) for (00) and (11) respectively)..?

Comment: we are assuming 1 as 'up' and 0 down spin in the direction of measurement..

Comment: Rotating the measurement basis will not change the state in the way you claim.